# Firebase Realtime Database UID different from Authentication UID

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to call for the UID that firebase provides and register it to the Realtime Database. For some reason the two UIDs are different. I think Authentication UID is changing after I register the original UID to Realtime Database. Perhaps the way I am calling the UID is wrong?

Authentication UID: zD40xuce4SWPiidMGOm62hFWOFP2

Realtime Database UID: rhqgglru9FXV5jhITSQmpqwBdc53

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_user);

    email = findViewById(R.id.email_create);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password_create);
    con_password = findViewById(R.id.password_confirm);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    registerBtn = findViewById(R.id.Register);


    registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String txt_email = email.getText().toString();
            String txt_password = password.getText().toString();
            String txt_con_password = con_password.getText().toString();

            FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ;
            Toast.makeText(New_User.this, "" + currentFirebaseUser.getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String txt_UID = currentFirebaseUser.getUid();

            //check empty fields
            if (txt_email.isEmpty() || txt_password.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(New_User.this, "Please fill all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //check passwords match
            else if (!txt_password.equals(txt_con_password)){
                Toast.makeText(New_User.this, "Passwords are not matching", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else{
                databaseReference.child("User ID").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasChild(txt_UID)) {
                            Toast.makeText(New_User.this, "User ID is taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            registerUser(txt_email, txt_password, txt_UID);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

            }

        }
    });
}

private void registerUser(String email, String password, String UID) {

    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(New_User.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            //doesnt upload login information into realtime database, but registers account
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                databaseReference.child("User ID").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        databaseReference.child("User ID").child(UID).child("email").setValue(email);
                        databaseReference.child("User ID").child(UID).child("password").setValue(password);

                        Toast.makeText(New_User.this, "User registered successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(New_User.this, PhysicalParameters.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
                FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                Toast.makeText(New_User.this, "Registering user successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Intent intent = new Intent(New_User.this, Welcome_Page.class);
                //startActivity(intent);
            }else {

                Toast.makeText(New_User.this, "Failed Registration: " + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
fAuth.getUid()
```

**For more reference. This is my project**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.face.Face;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText mFullName, mEmail, mPassword, mPhone;
    Button mRegisterBtn, pickimagebtn;
    TextView mLoginHereBtn,imgsourcetxtview;

    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    String encryptionimagestring;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView ProfileImage;
    SparseArray<Face> faces;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    int count = 0;
    private byte encryptionkey[] = {9, 115, 51, 86, 105, 4, -31, 23, -68, 88, 17, 20, 3, -105, 119, -53};
    private Cipher cipher, decipher;
    private SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        imgsourcetxtview =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.imagesoucetxtview);
        imgsourcetxtview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        imgsourcetxtview.setSingleLine();

        //pick image

        pickimagebtn = findViewById(R.id.pickimagebtn);
        pickimagebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CropImage.activity(null)
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                        .start(Register.this);
            }
        });


        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            decipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionkey, "AES");

        mFullName = findViewById(R.id.Register_FullName);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.Email);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.Password);
        mPhone = findViewById(R.id.Register_Phone);
        mRegisterBtn = findViewById(R.id.Register_button);
        mLoginHereBtn = findViewById(R.id.LoginHere);
        mFullName = findViewById(R.id.Register_FullName);

        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class).putExtra("fuid", String.valueOf(fAuth.getUid())));
            finish();
        }

        mRegisterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mFullName.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    mFullName.setError("Name is required.");
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    mEmail.setError("Email is required.");
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mPhone.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    mPhone.setError("Phone is required.");
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    mPassword.setError("Password is required.");
                    return;
                }

                if (password.length() < 6) {
                    mPassword.setError("Password must be >= 6 characters.");
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imgsourcetxtview.getText().toString().trim())) {
                   imgsourcetxtview.setError("Image is required.");
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inMutable = true;
                    detectFace(options);
                    if (faces.size() < 1) {
                        imgsourcetxtview.setError("Can't detect face.");
                        return;
                    }
                    if (faces.size() > 1) {
                        imgsourcetxtview.setError("More than one face is detected.");
                        return;
                    }
                }


                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            //add information to firebase

                            myRef.child("Account").child(fAuth.getUid()).child("name").setValue(AESEncryptionmethod(mFullName.getText().toString()));
                            myRef.child("Account").child(fAuth.getUid()).child("phone").setValue(AESEncryptionmethod(mPhone.getText().toString()));
                            myRef.child("Account").child(fAuth.getUid()).child("email").setValue(AESEncryptionmethod(mEmail.getText().toString()));
                            myRef.child("Account").child(fAuth.getUid()).child("photo").setValue(encryptionimagestring);
                            myRef.child("Account").child(fAuth.getUid()).child("coin").setValue("0");
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "User created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class).putExtra("fuid", String.valueOf(fAuth.getUid())));

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Error!" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        mLoginHereBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private String AESEncryptionmethod(String string) {
        byte[] stringByte = string.getBytes();
        byte[] encryptedByte = new byte[stringByte.length];
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            encryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(stringByte);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String returnString = null;
        try {
            returnString = new String(encryptedByte, "ISO-8859-1");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // handle result of CropImageActivity
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), result.getUri());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                imgsourcetxtview.setText(String.valueOf(result.getUri()));

                Toast.makeText(
                        this, "Cropping successful, Sample: " + result.getUri(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                encryptionimage(bitmap);
            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cropping failed: " + result.getError(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
    public void encryptionimage(Bitmap bitmap){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
        byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
        String string=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] stringByte = string.getBytes();
        byte[] encryptedByte = new byte[stringByte.length];
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            encryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(stringByte);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String returnString = null;
        try {
            returnString = new String(encryptedByte, "ISO-8859-1");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        encryptionimagestring = returnString;

    }
    private void  detectFace(BitmapFactory.Options options) {
        /*Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.test1,
                options
        );*/
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,0,0,null);

        FaceDetector faceDetector = new FaceDetector.Builder(Register.this).setTrackingEnabled(false)
                .build();
        if(!faceDetector.isOperational()){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Could not set up Face Detector!").show();
            return;
        }

        Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
         faces = faceDetector.detect(frame);
        /*for(int i=0; i<faces.size(); i++) {
            Face thisFace = faces.valueAt(i);
            float x1 = thisFace.getPosition().x;
            float y1 = thisFace.getPosition().y;
            float x2 = x1 + thisFace.getWidth();
            float y2 = y1 + thisFace.getHeight();
            canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(x1, y1, x2, y2), 2, 2, paint);
        }*/
       // imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),tempBitmap));
    }
}
```